# Distorted coin - probability, expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A distorted coin indicates Number with probability p (0 < p < 1) and it indicates Head with probability 1-p. 
The coin is thrown until Number appears for the first time.
The random variable X indicates how many throws are performed in total (that is, including the last one with number).

Determine the set of all possible results, the probability function and the expected value of X.

For which values of $p$ does it hold $E[X] < 10$?

$$$$

I have done the following:

How could we determine the set of all possible results?

The probability function is defined as $\displaystyle{P(X=i)=(1-p)^{i-1}\cdot p}$ or not?

The expected value is $\displaystyle{E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\cdot P(X=x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\cdot (1-p)^{i-1}\cdot p}$ with $x_i=0$ or $x_i=1$. Is this correct?

Comment: We have $$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty i(1-p)^{i-1}p=\frac{1}{p}$$ The formula for $P(X=i)$ is correct.

Comment: Hence $E(X)<10$ holds for $p>\frac{1}{10}$

Comment: At the expected value do we take the infinity sum because we don't know how many times we thow the coin? @Peter

Comment: Yes because it could take arbitary long to get the result (in theory). It is also intuitively plausible that we need $10$ throws in the average if the probability is $\frac{1}{10}$ , for example. The problem is called "first-success-problem"

Comment: Ah ok! Which is the set of all possible results in this case? Is it maybe the set of all possible tuples with elements $0$ or $1$ ? @Peter

Comment: We stop at the first success, so the sequence is $0\cdots 01$ with $i-1$ zeros , if $0$ denotes "failure" and $1$ denores "success". We need $i$ tries , so $X=i$. The possible results for $X$ are the positive integers $1,2,3,\cdots $